# Modify html template

Tags: php, regex

I'm working on web application based on PHP that simply send emails to clients,admins are able to create templates in html format , this template store locally in a folder , this template should have a link contain client email address for example a button

```
<form method="post" action="http://my-server-address/myWebDirectory/clients.php?email=client_email">
    <input type="submit" class="button button2" value="Some Value"></center>
</form>
```

I'm looking for an automated way that allows me to import html template and replace specific value with client email address like above button by insert client email into URL

```
hxxp://my-server-address/myWebDirectory/clients.php?email=[client_email].
```

currently i convert the html template into php and insert client email to it [client emails stored in database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a web template system like [mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php).